# should you include file in xml or have it in a two step process?

Tags: c#, xml, base64, file-transfer, cdata

I have to implement a way to transfer between many organizations(unknown number) some information, name/address/etc, and a unknown number of files associated to that information.

when I'm saying unknown files, it could be a xml file of over 100 meg, if they are embedded

the transfer will be done over xml so the question is;

should i allow embedded files using base64 in elements or have a 2 steps process which would be

1. send me the xml file with a kind of pointer in a element, let say filenames
2. send the files with the specific filenames in the xml

or is there a third solution?

I have to deserialize the xml into an object, do some manipulation then saving it in a database.

(I currently have a throw away prototype using the 2 steps process)

Comment: I would keep it as one if at all possible as I dislike dealing with multiple files when one will do. If you do with to keep separate XML documents/resources, then package everything up in a container (e.g. ZIP) - this is what Microsoft does for its newer Office file formats. There might already be standard schemes for cross-linking XML documents/resources.

Comment: going home for now so i will read what was say later tonight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the files in the XML, this would make it unwieldy. Instead, reference the file names from the XML and then zip the XML and files up into one bundle and send that.

Comment: I was thinking of that solution and it seem to be what is going to be done, at least i will recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure to consider the expected evolution of the data, how change occurs across the parts of the document, and how many parties have an interest in the updates.**

At the one end of the spectrum, the data will never change, the parts are all static, and updates aren't an issue to anyone.  A one-shot broadcast of a single large file (or zipped set of files) is good enough.  I'd lean toward a zipped archive with linked components over an embedding/encoding solution here.

The other end of the spectrum calls for a "third solution," as you say.  The data changes frequently and independently, some parts of the massive document change while others remain constant, and many parties are interested in having access to the current version of the evolving data.  Here, a linked representation of the various parts of the resource as references to network-shared parts, possibly independently version controlled, would have a major advantage.  **[Linked data](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html) is a robust solution worth considering over monolithic distribution of a massive file.**